# Wayona mini usb WiFi adapter does not work

Tags: wireless, usb

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and have found that my usb wifi adapter(wayona mini usb) is not working. I am new to Ubuntu, how can i get my usb adapter to working?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: This is a Chinese product marketed with the name Wayona in Indian sub-continent. So it is difficult to get help from outside India until you update the post with more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git 
git clone https://github.com/porjo/mt7601.git 
cd mt7601/src 
make 
sudo make install 
sudo mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/ 
sudo cp RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/ 
sudo modprobe mt7601Usta
```

I also searched many places to find a solution and this really worked for me and it works like a charm for Wayona mini usb WiFi adapter.

References:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2270202

Answer (score 0):

Get a wired network connection. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type in these commands to run them:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/porjo/mt7601u.git 
cd mt7601/src
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
sudo cp RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
sudo modprobe mt7601u
```

If the kernel gets updated, i.e., you updated your Ubuntu system, type:

```
cd mt7601/src
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe mt7601u
```

Comment: "https://github.com/porjo/mt7601.git " has been migrated to "https://github.com/porjo/mt7601u.git" i presume.